# Two references to object, but when modify it by one, second still show unchanged object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fix an issue in a JS plugin and after debugging I discovered that sometimes one variable is changing another, sometimes not. So I placed this code:

```
var a = $('#w3').data('fileinput').initialPreviewConfig[index];
var b = previewCache.data[id].config[index];
if (a === Object(a) && b === Object(b)) { //check a and b are objects
   if(a == b && a === b) { //check they reference same object
      a = null; //set a to null, so b should be null as well
      if(a === null && b !== null) {
         console.log("This should not be printed!"); //but it is not!
      }
   }
}
```

and the output is `This should not be printed`.

If both variables are pointing to same object why modifing by one does not change another? What can cause this, event or something like overrided operator?

**Edit:**
I was trying to simplify code, but this without a and b sometimes output `This should not be printed`, sometimes not.

```
if ($('#w3').data('fileinput').initialPreviewConfig[index] === Object($('#w3').data('fileinput').initialPreviewConfig[index]) && previewCache.data[id].config[index] === Object(previewCache.data[id].config[index])) {
   if($('#w3').data('fileinput').initialPreviewConfig[index] == previewCache.data[id].config[index] && $('#w3').data('fileinput').initialPreviewConfig[index] === previewCache.data[id].config[index]) {
      $('#w3').data('fileinput').initialPreviewConfig[index] = null;
      if($('#w3').data('fileinput').initialPreviewConfig[index] === null && previewCache.data[id].config[index] !== null) {
            console.log("This should not be printed!");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Setting a to null doesn't modify memory a was pointing to, only makes a point to null, so b remains unchanged, this is how variables work.

Comment: Are you trying to *simplify* the code, or are you trying to *fix* it?

Comment: @Bergi I was trying to simplify debugging code in order to fix plugin in which sometimes two variables are modified simultaneously, but sometimes one.

Comment: Instead of checking `….initialPreviewConfig[index] == ….config[index]`, you might want to check `….initialPreviewConfig == ….config` for that. Oh, and btw, `a == b && a === b` can always be simplified to `a === b` only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this

```
a = null
```

doesn't set anything else to `null` but `a`.

`b` is left unchanged.

You can think of variables in JS as named pointers to values stored somewhere in memory.

For example, the following code:

```
var obj = { name: 'bob' };
var a = obj;
var b = obj;
```

produces two variables, `a` and `b`, that both point to `obj` in memory.

[image: a and b pointing to an object]

Now when you do

```
a = null
```

You're just making `a` point to `null` while `b` is still pointing to `obj`.

[image: a pointing to null and b pointing to object]

Comment: thanks, that explains that behaviour, but could you look at the updated question?

Comment: what if i want to null object in memory and still have pointed a and b to it?

Comment: you cannot `null` an object in memory, you `null` the pointer to it. The garbage collector deals with actually removing the object. To `null` something just means to point it to a special place in memory that represents `null`.